# Unit test for exception assertion fails despite expected and actual value matching a sad path

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, exception

I have a function below that throws exception when failed to deserialize:

```kotlin
fun deserialize(payload: SdkBytes): List<Event>? {
    return try {
        val response = Json.decodeFromString<Response>(payload.asUtf8String())
        return response.body
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        // if fails to deserialize
        logger.error(e)
        null
    }
}
```

I have the following unit test to test when the exception is thrown:

```kotlin
fun testWhenMalformedJson() {
    val body = "test body"
    val bytes = SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(body)

    expectCatching { deserialize(bytes) }
        .isFailure()
        .isA<IllegalArgumentException>()
}
```

When I try to run the test it fails with the following error:

```
  ▼ Expect that Success(null):
    ✗ is failure
      returned null

  Expected :null
  Actual   :null
```

I am unable to understand why my test is failing if actual and expected values are same.

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic here, but maybe it is `null` vs. `"null"`? Also, I don't think `deserialize()` throws in the case of malformed input as it clearly catches the exception and returns null instead.

Comment: I have edited my question, I mean to test that its a failure and exception was catched

Comment: I am not retuning string "null" but rather null so I am not able to understand what does the message actually means

Comment: (Yeah, a string was my initial guess too. Of course, it could be _any_ object which gave `null` when you called its `toString()` method, but I can't think of any other common types which would.)

Comment: I don't know this Strikt assertion library you probably use here, but to be honest, this `expectCatching()` is super-confusing to me. If the function is expected to not throw, then it doesn't make sense to test it for any specific exception. If I read the docs correctly, then `isFailure()` actually means you expect the function to throw. You need to use `isSuccess()`. But I have no idea why the library says the `null` was expected. I believe it expected an exception and this is why the test failed.

Comment: Maybe this is just me, but the documentation there is really bad. It is not very clear what `isFailure()`/`isSuccess()` actually mean. Sometimes it mentions `isFailure()` and sometimes `failed()` - it doesn't explain if this is the same and the name changed between versions or these are different things.

Comment: hmm I just checked this: expectThat(deserialize(bytes)).isNull() and seems to return true. I think expectCatching expects the funtion to throw an exception which you can then assert in {} block but since here we are are already catching the exception so it just returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is recommended to use [`SerializationException`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-serialization-exception/) to catch any decoding-specific errors because `IllegalArgumentException` is a generic exception that can also be thrown if the decoded input is not a valid instance of `T`. See: [kotlinx.serialization.json - decodeFromString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json/decode-from-string.html)

In regard to the test, it is failing for the correct reason. No exception is being thrown from your `deserialize` method because it is being caught by the `catch` block.

Instead, one way to test this logic would be asserting if null is being returned. (assuming `response.body` returns a non-nullable type).

```kotlin
fun deserialize(payload: String): List<String>? {
    return try {
        return Json.decodeFromString<List<String>>(payload)
    } catch (e: SerializationException) {
        null // if fails to deserialize
    }
}

@Test
fun `should return null when an exception is thrown`() {
    val payload = "invalid"
    val response = deserialize(payload)
    assert(response == null)
}

@Test
fun `should return a list when deserialization is successful`() {
    val payload = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
    val response = deserialize(payload)
    assert(response != null)
}
```

If you want to be more granular, you can static mockk the Json decoder to throw an exception using a library like [Mockk](https://mockk.io/) to ensure null can only be returned by the catch block:

```kotlin
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockkObject
import kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

@Test
fun `should return null when an exception is thrown`() {
    mockkObject(Json.Default) {
        every { Json.decodeFromString<List<String>>(any()) } throws SerializationException("invalid")
        val response = deserialize("any string...")
        assert(response == null)
    }
}
```